# Declaring the field of a class without prefixing it with the class

Tags: java

```
private static final Color DEFAULT_PEN_COLOR   = BLACK;

private static final Color DEFAULT_CLEAR_COLOR = WHITE;
```

This is a part of my code thats is having an error that says that the symbols BLACK and WHITE cannot be identified, even when I put import java.awt.Color. What do I need to do?

Comment: Use `Color.BLACK` and `Color.WHITE` instead.

Comment: Color.BLACK and Color.WHITE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [static imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) if you don't want to prefix the Color class :

```
import static java.awt.Color.*;
```

or else you have to prefix the fields with `Color`:

```
Color.BLACK 
Color.WHITE
```

Comment: I believe you need to import either both colors explicitly or use wildcard on your import `import static java.awt.Color.BLACK` or `import static java.awt.Color.*`

Comment: @Samuel Indeed thank you.It is not required only when the import specifies a variable and Color is indeed not a variable.